# Looking at the first character of a string for every element in a list

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with a column called 'picture'; that column has values that either start with a number or letter. What I'm trying to do is create a new column that checks whether or not the value starts with a letter or number, and populate that new column accordingly. I'm using np.where, and my code is below (raw_master is the dataframe, 'database' is the new column):

```
def iaps_or_naps(x):
    if x in ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]:
        return True
    else:
        return False
raw_master['database'] = np.where(iaps_or_naps(raw_master.picture[?][0])==True, 'IAPS', 'NAPS')
```

My issue is that if I just do `raw_master.picture[0]`, that checks the value of the entire string, which is not what I need. I need the first character; however, if I do `raw_master.picture[0][0]`, that will just evaluate to the first character of the first row for the whole dataframe. BTW, the question mark just means I'm not sure what to put there.

How can I get it so it takes the first character of the string for every row?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You also don't need the `==True` in your `np.where`. `np.where` evaluates a boolean, and assigns the first string you pass it (`'IAPS'`) to be what is assigned if the condition is `True`, and the second string `'NAPS'` if the condition is false). Adding `==True` is an unnecessary evaluation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write your own function for this. Take this small df as an example:

```
 s = pd.DataFrame(['3asd', 'asd', '3423', 'a123'])
```

looks like:

```
      0
0  3asd
1   asd
2  3423
3  a123
```

using a pandas builtin:

```
# checking first column, s[0], first letter, str[0], to see if it is digit.
# if so, assigning IAPS, if not, assigning NAPS
 s['database'] = np.where(s[0].str[0].str.isdigit(), 'IAPS', 'NAPS')
```

output:

```
      0 database
0  3asd     IAPS
1   asd     NAPS
2  3423     IAPS
3  a123     NAPS
```

Applying this to your dataframe:

```
raw_master['database'] = np.where(raw_master['picture'].str[0].str.isdigit(), 'IAPS', 'NAPS')
```

Comment: Thank you my friend! It worked. So, what is the str[0] part doing? Not familiar with that particular syntax. It's taking the first character of whatever string is in the 'picture' row?

Comment: @BrianWinston that is exactly right! Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC you can just test if the first char is an int using `pd.to_numeric`

```
np.where(pd.to_numeric(df['your_col'].str[0],errors='coerce').isnull(),'IAPS'   
,'NAPS')                                                             #  ^ not a number
  #^ number
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a mapping function such as `apply` which iterates over each element in the column, this way accessing the first character with indexing `[0]`

```
df['new_col'] = df['picture'].apply(lambda x: 'IAPS' if x[0].str.isdigit() else 'NAPS')
```